# A simple time complexity in C

Tags: c, recursion, time-complexity

Can you guys please tell me what's the **time** complexity of `f3`? 
I'm thinking **sqrt(n).log(n)** but the official answer is **n**. 
Any ideas why?

```
#define PARTS 4

void f3(int n) {
    if (n < 4)
        return;

    for (int i = 0; i * i < n; i++)
        printf("%d", i);

    for (int i = 0; i < PARTS; i++)
        f3(n / PARTS);
}
```

Comment: Paste the code as text, please.

Comment: excellent question if the code was text. Do you expect us to mentally compile it? or retype it maybe. Please type/paste it here.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity depends on that of `printf`: if you can assume that `printf("%d",i)` has a constant cost, then the time complexity seems to be **O(N + k.sqrt(N))**, with k=-1. Since **sqrt(N)** is dominated by **N**, this simplifies into **O(N)**.

```
        cost(4*N) = 4*cost(N) + sqrt(4*N)
4*N + k*sqrt(4*N) = 4*N + 4*k*sqrt(N) + 2*sqrt(N)
              2*k = 4*k+2
                k = -1
```

If `printf("%d",i)` has a complexity of **log(i)**, taking into account the number of digits produced by the conversion of `i` to base 10, the overall complexity is more difficult to assess: **k.sqrt(N)** becomes **k.log(N).sqrt(N)**, which is still dominated by **N**.

Comment: too bad the question has this damn image but nice answer just because of the "sqrt(N) is dominated by N" bit.

Comment: Looks like `O(N sqrt(N))` to me... There is a recursion in a loop down there.. it's complicating things

Comment: the sqrt loop is not calling the recursive function. So it's just complexity noise.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Right. So sqrt is irrelevant. It's more like `O(N * N/4 * N/8 * ....)`. Is it `O(N log N)` then? Update : Oh.. no. It is up to PARTS, not to N.. So yeah, a noise

Comment: having to click on this damn image really ruins it for me. Now I'm confused.